# Cards with margins in columns

Tags: w3.css

I have a 2 column grid on a row with 2 cards. I would also like a margin so the cards are not touching each other, but when I add `w3-margin` to my cards, they wrap onto different lines.

How can I have the margin around the cards without it affecting the column integrity? Thanks.

Fiddle (remove instances of `w3-margin` to see it working): https://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/7o6bnosu/

```
<div class="w3-row-padding">

  <div class="w3-col s6 m6 l6 w3-card-2 w3-yellow w3-margin">
    <p>Cards should be on the same row with some space between them.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-col s6 m6 l6 w3-card-2 w3-green w3-margin">
    <p>Cards should be on the same row with some space between them.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was just trying to do too much in one div. If anyone is interested, here is the my solution.

```
<div class="w3-col m6">
  <div class="w3-card-2 w3-margin w3-light-grey w3-center" style="">
    ...content...
  </div>
</div>
```